# Adding JavaScript and CSS to a particular menu page

Tags: 7, javascript

I have set up [a Drupal 7 web site](http://preferans.de) with a few custom blocks and menus written by me.

I have [a non-Drupal PHP script](http://preferans.de/top20.php) displaying users (some of them are external, i.e. not stored in drupal tables) as a table with the [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) jQuery plugin.

I would like to rewrite that script as a Drupal menu, so that it can be called as http://preferans.de/top.

The content of **my.module** is the following.

```
function my_menu() {
  $items['top'] = array (
    'title' => 'Top',
    'description' => 'Top',
    'page callback' => 'my_top_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'file' => 'my.top.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

The content of **my.top.inc** is the following.

```
function my_top_callback() {
  return array (
    'top_table' => array (
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => generate_html_table_with_php(),
    ),
  );
}
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to add the CSS and JavaScript code, so that it is available for the **/top** page, but not for any other Drupal paths.

I should probably call:

```
   drupal_add_css('/demo_table_jui.css', 'file');
   drupal_add_css('/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css', 'file');
   drupal_add_js('/jquery.dataTables.min.js', 'file');
   drupal_add_js('
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#rating").dataTable( {
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
          });
        ', 'inline');
```

(Please see the head-section of [my original non-Drupal script](http://preferans.de/top20.php)).

How do I limit these calls to the **/top** page and where should I perform these calls?
Should I put them in a hook, or by adding some properties to my menu?

Comment: `'file path'` is not necessary, if the file is inside the directory containing the module that defines the menu callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, CSS and JavaScript files are added with [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7), which allows those files to be aggregated together, when aggregation is enabled.

Using `hook_init()` (I suggest you not to do this, anyway) you could conditionally add the files basing on the page being visited.

```
function my_init() {
  if (arg(0) == 'top') {
    // Add the files.
  }
}
```

The reason I don't suggest you to do this is that the hook would be called for every pages, including the ones you are not adding the files. `hook_init()` is generally used to add files to each page.

You can add those files in the menu callback (a.k.a., the page callback); if the menu callback is a form builder function, then you can use the `#attached` property, as the following code.

```
$form['#attached']['css'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.css',
);

$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js',
);
```

About the inline code you are adding, I would recommend you to put also that in a file, and to use Drupal behaviors instead of `$(document).ready()`. If you need to pass arguments to the JavaScript code, you can use JavaScript settings (see [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to understand in details how to pass settings to JavaScript code).
[Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722) explains in details how to manage JavaScript code in Drupal 7, and the section titles *Behaviors* reports how Drupal behaviors are changed in the latest Drupal version.

Comment: Using hook_init() would cause the code to be added to every page. The question was for how to add them to a specific menu callback.

Comment: That is why I said _generally_. I was not suggesting that using `hook_init()` is the solution in this case, but I was explaining why `hook_init()` is usually used.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to add it to a particular path. Something like function my_init() {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_css(....); drupal_add_js(....);
  }
}
but for the /top and not the front page.

Comment: @Alexander as kiamlaluno explains in the answer, if you make these calls inside the `page callback` function it will only be applied on these specific pages.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the code in your menu callback. Instead of adding the JS code inline, I would suggest that you create your own JS file.

```
function my_top_callback() {
  drupal_add_css('/demo_table_jui.css');
  drupal_add_css('/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css');
  drupal_add_js('/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my') . '/my.js');
  return array (
    'top_table' => array (
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => generate_html_table_with_php(),
    ),
  );
}
```

You should then add the `my.js` file to your my module. Notice that `$`isn't a global variable in Drupal 7 instead use `jQuery`:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rating").dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

You could also make this into a JavaScript behavior which is the recommended thing to do. That would look something like this:

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.my = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $("#rating").dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm confused - what does this do: (function($) { .... })(jQuery);

Comment: @Alexander: That's what in JavaScript is called a closure. It's a technique to make sure your variables doesn't impact other JavaScript code, as they all share the same name space, the global window object. This would allow you to run fx the prototype JS library which also uses the `$` sign without conflict.